# Installation failed with message "INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_PACKAGE_NAME"

Tags: android

So I was doing some refactoring of package names in my project and now i'm no longer able to install my app. Right around the same time that I updated to the most current version of android studio. I believe that may be the problem because I think i did the refactoring before the upgrade,  I just don't remember 100%

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dodgingfire" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/dodging_fire_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".gamemain.GameMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is how I have my packages organized

http://prntscr.com/gcrw99

This is the full error message when I try to run my app

```
Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_PACKAGE_NAME: Invalid manifest package: must have at least one '.' separator.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

Even when I accept to delete the existing application, It still gives me an error and doesn't install my app let alone run it.

Comment: Manifest package name is not the one that ends up in the APK. Have a look at `applicationId` in your build.gradle file.

Comment: Expanded as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `package` name in your source manifest file is not actually the one that ends up in the APK being installed. During manifest merging process, the final package name is based on the `applicationId` value in your app's `build.gradle` file.

As the error message says, you need at least one `.` in the package name.

Other reasons for `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_BAD_PACKAGE_NAME` can be found in [`PackageParser#validateName()` source](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java#1360).